# How to obtain access token in webapp without login form (keycloak)

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, keycloak, access-token

The goal is to get an access token from Keycloak to use that token for API calls.

The app should not require any login from the user, so it just need to authenticate itself.

I was planning to use client_credentials flow for that. However, client_credentials require the client to be `confidential`. And confidential clients have CORS issues in Keycloak.

If I switch to a `public` client I cannot use `client_credentials` flow anymore.

What is the best way to continue from here? Maybe I need to use `password credentials` flow and public client, because client credentials are going to be exposed anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Create a **new** client, confidential, and activate **service account** on it.

You will be able to authenticate with `grant_type=client_credentials` using the client_id and client_secret as credentials (hence the *service* account, it's not a user account).

You will obtain an access token, no refresh token, and you'll simply have to reconnect again using the same credentials when the access_token will be expired.

For the permissions of this service account on the REST API check the 'scope' tab and the new 'Service Account' tab. You'll need access on some of the 'realm-managment' roles.

About creation new client application, it's not unusual to have several clients for the same real application, like you could have a bearer-only client for the API part, and a confidential one for other things. I do not know what is you CORS problems with confidential clients.

- *confidential* clients are used by full stack applications (not front+back ones), and **service accounts** (B-to-B).
- *bearer_only* is for API backs
- *public* is **only** for front application (like angular, vuejs, etc) where you cannot store a client secret and the security depends only on the redirect_uri filter.

Comment: That was the point - I wanted to use client_creddentials with confidential client, but it is not usable for FE app. So we had to rethink the solution altogether :)(

Comment: what is FE ? if it's a front app it must not contain any secret, nothing is secret in a front app, do not reach the SSO API from a front app directly, you need a back proxy application.

Comment: Yep, FE is a front-end app.