# Keycloak 18 disable user access to user console

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-18

I need to disable users to be able to access Keycloak user console under `/realms/REALM_NAME/account/` I want users to be able only to register/login/forgot password/remember me/ Only admin user should be able to access `ADMIN` console. But user should not be able to access `USER` console.
How to configure it with Keycloak 18?

Comment: have you tried disabling the account client in the realm?

Comment: Thank you! Works! I have already disabled the user account console. Another question - if the user wants to change the password - should I use the Keykloak REST API to implement this from my app?

Comment: yes, maybe via the REST api, use service account to connect the rest API and give this service account rights on the realm-managment, I think I described it a little here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73416672/550618